# How do I prevent Ubuntu 12.04 from locking, when using Win7 in VirtualBox?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, virtualbox, lock-screen, focus

I use Ubuntu 12.04 plus Windows 7 from VirtualBox.
The thing is that, when I am in Windows "too long" (longer than the time after which Ubuntu normally locks), Ubuntu locks.
It's not expected, because I still use PC.
I would only like to lock it, when I don't use mouse/ keyboard at all.

Conclusion is that probably, when the focus is in Windows, Ubuntu doesn't know about that (doesn't have info on keyboard/ mouse moves).

Has anyone else experienced similar issue?
Is there a way to prevent it?

Many thanks in advance,
Konrad

after edit:
- Guest additions are installed for Windows 7,
- I don't use Unity
- I don't use Compiz
- to clarify: locking occurs, when I go back to Ubuntu from Windows, after that time

Comment: Had you installed the [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)?

Comment: yes, I had. however, as far as I know, this issue also occurs when Guest Additions are not installed.